# How to check existence by array of uniq numbers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have `Disclosure` model that have `accession_number` column. The column have unique constraint.

And when there is an array of accession_numbers, how can I know if there is accession_numbers that is not used yet.

I'm currently check existence for every numbers, but I think there is better way for this behavior.

```
accession_numbers.select{|number| !Disclosure.where(accession_number: number).exists?}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query for all disclosures which have an accession_number in your array.

```
existing = Disclosure.where(accession_number: accession_numbers).pluck(:accession_number)
```

Then just remove the existing ones from your array

```
accession_numbers - existing
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have an unique constraint at DB level,

```
exiting_accessions = Disclosure.pluck(:accession_number)
```

results in an array of existing accesssions.

`accession_array - existing_accessions` results in an array of unused accessions.